# Slow performance with Javascript/jQuery text animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This is a simplified and explained version of my code:

```
    var ptext=parr.find('div.ptext');   //Text Container

    var pt=ptext.html();                //Text Container's string
    var pdv=[pt.split(" ")];            //Text Container's array of words
        pdv.push(pdv[0].length);    //Write also the number of words

    var ht=hp.html();               //Text Container's new string
    var hdv=[ht.split(" ")];            //Text Container's new array of words
    hdv.push(hdv[0].length);            //New number of words

    var kakaka=0;                       //If they begin with the same,
    for (var j=0;j<hdv[0].length;j++){  //Animate only from the position
        if (hdv[0][j]==pdv[0][j])   //where they differ
            kakaka+=2;
    }

    window.clearTimeout(ptext.data('curt'));  //Clear current animation's interval
    ptext.data('count',kakaka);      //Set starting position    
    ptext.data('curt',                      //Set interval's var into object
        window.setInterval((function (item,pdv,hdv,text_callback) {
                return function() {       //item = text obj, text_callback= callback function
                        var i=item.data('count');
                            i=(i==undefined)?0:1+i;
                        item.data('count',i);     //increase counter
                                //first phase - remove old text
                        if (i<=pdv[1])       // go on
                        {
                            item.html((pdv[0].slice(0,pdv[1]-i)).join(' '));
                        }       //if reached the position, add new text
                        else if (i<=pdv[1]+hdv[1])
                        {
                            item.html((hdv[0].slice(0,i-pdv[1])).join(' '));
                        }        //if finish clear timeout and call callback
                        else {
                            item.data('count',0);
                            window.clearTimeout(item.data('curt'));
                            text_callback();
                        }
                }
            })(ptext,pdv,hdv,text_callback),8)   //8 = supposed interval
       );


}
```

It gets the words from the div, removes them one by one quickly, and then populates it with the new text.

It uses .setInterval() function, which was supposed to callback every 8ms. This works beautifully on my i5 CPU, but it is terrifically slow on an i3 laptop.

Could you give some advice on how to increase performance?

Comment: why are you picking them out one by one? what does this code do in the big picture? we could suggest alternatives in your approach.

Comment: Well it has a description text, that one paragraph long, and it's a design feature to make transition from one description into another - word by word.

Comment: I'd opt for a quicker, less CPU intense solution that involves just applying it to the entire sentence. You're pushing the browser to it's limit, and you're users aren't going to care about your cool feature if it makes their experience slow. Also, your choice of variable names makes me want to run away screaming. Consider using something a bit more meaningful for the names. :)

Comment: An 8 ms interval is 125 frames per second. That's a bit demanding.

Comment: Not really for something so simple, and in a good browser, but what's the purpose of something that no human can hope to see? You can do more work in longer intervals with the same effect.

Comment: You are mistaken if you think you a human cannot see every bit of it. Dahrn... I wish you could come to my house and actually see how it works ^.^ **Edit** but yeah, you've got some point, that if we do not accomodate for the lags, we could actually do 2 words per batch to make it render at the standart 60fps rate - makes sense :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the function that did it perfectly, the whole idea was to wrap it in SPANS, then for each span we would change the visibility, and when it gets to the reverse phase, replace with different text wrapped in spans.

I don't guarantee you will ever understand anything, but you can surely get an idea how I solved it. Note, basically the main inputs are pdv, and hdv - are the word arrays of input text and output text.

```
function letsdance(obj,op,type,text_callback){  //animate text

    if (text_callback==undefined) var text_callback=function(){};

    var parr=obj.parents('.pconter');
    var ptext=parr.find('div.ptext');


    var pt=ptext.html();

    var ppp=ptext.children();
    var pdv=[[]];
    for (var i=0;i<ppp.length;i++)
        pdv[0].push(    ppp[i].outerHTML    );



    if (ppp.length==0){
    var pdv=[pt.split(" ")];
        for (var i=0;i<pdv[0].length;i++)
            pdv[0][i]='<span>'+pdv[0][i]+'</span>';
        ptext.html(pdv[0].join(' '));
    }

    pdv.push(pdv[0].length-1);

    if (op){
        if (type===1)
            {
                var ht=obj.html();
            }
        else if (type==2)
            {
                var ht=ptext.data('orig');  
            }
        else {
        var ide=(obj.attr('id').match(/_[\da-zA-Z]*_[\da-zA-Z]*$/))[0];
        var hp=parr.find('div.hptext[id$="'+ide+'"]');
        var ht=hp.html();   
        }
        var hdv=[ht.split(" ")];
            hdv.push(hdv[0].length-1);  
    } else {    
        var current_selection=parseInt(ptext.data('current_section'));
        if (current_selection>0){
            var pto=ptext.siblings('.subptext[id$="NN'+current_selection+'"]').html();
            }
        else 
            var pto=ptext.data('orig');

        var hdv=[pto.split(" ")];
            hdv.push(hdv[0].length-1);  
    }

    var kakaka=0;
    var kaka=false;
    for (var i=0;i<=hdv[1];i++){
        if (pdv[0][i]!=undefined&&!kaka&&hdv[0][i]==pdv[0][i].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")&&!/invis/.test(pdv[0][i])){
                        kakaka+=1;  
        }
        else {
            kaka=true;
            hdv[0][i]='<span class="invis">'+hdv[0][i]+'</span>'; 
        }
    }
    var invi_count=pdv[1];
    for (invi_count;invi_count>=0;invi_count--)
        if (!/invis/.test(pdv[0][invi_count])) break;

    window.clearInterval(ptext.data('curt'));
    ptext.data('count',invi_count).data('index',kakaka).data('phase',0)//data('skip',0);            
    ptext.data('curt',
        window.setInterval((function (item,pdv,hdv,text_callback) {
                return function() {
                    var i=item.data('count');      
                    var phase=item.data('phase');      
                    var index=item.data('index');    
                    switch (phase)
                    {
                        case 0:
                                item.children(':eq('+i+')').addClass('invis');
                                if (i>index)    
                                    item.data('count',i-1);
                                else
                                    item.data('count',index).data('phase',1)
                                    .html((pdv[0].slice(0,index)).join(' ')).append(' '+hdv[0].slice(index,hdv[1]).join(' '));
                        break;  
                        case 1:
                                item.children(':eq('+i+')').removeClass('invis');
                                if (i<hdv[1])
                                    item.data('count',i+1);
                                else{
                                    //item.data('count',0).data('phase',0);
                                    window.clearInterval(item.data('curt'));
                                    text_callback();
                                }
                        break;      
                    }
                }
            })(ptext,pdv,hdv,text_callback),4)
       );


}
```

Comment: Anyway I don't care, because I found my answer, I'm just sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- try making the container have a set width and height to avoid repaint and reflow of the document. resize the element after the operation.
- then you can avoid array operations (split and join) and just use string operations directly.
- avoid repeated calls to the same element by storing references outside the looping operation
- use `text()` instead of `html()`, that way, the DOM only creates text nodes.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T3uLX/4/) and it runs very fast on my trusty Pentium 4

```
$(function() {

    function clearText(selector, callback) {
        //cache repeatedly used items
        var element = $(selector),
            elementText = element.text() + ' '; 

        //set element dimensions to fixed
        element.width(element.width());    
        element.height(element.height());

        (function erase() {
            if (elementText) {
                //use slice operations instead
                elementText = elementText.slice(elementText.indexOf(' ')+1);
                //use "text()"
                element.text(elementText);
                //loop
                setTimeout(function() {
                    erase();
                }, 8);
            } else {
                //set the dimensions back to auto
                element.width('auto').height('auto');   
                //execute callback returning the jQuery element
                callback.apply(element); 
            }
        }())

    }

    clearText('#foo', function() {
        //"this" is jQuery object "#foo"
        this.text('hello world');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job, you might want to change the lag between setTimeout calls. It could be made more self contained but I don't have the motivation right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Some support functions
(function(g) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    g.getText = function(el) {return el.textContent};
    g.setText = function(el, text) {el.textContent = text};
  }

  if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    g.getText = function(el) {return el.innerText};
    g.setText = function(el, text) {el.innerText = text};
  }
}(this));

function annoyUser(el, text) {
  var re = /\s+/g;
  var oText = getText(el).split(re);

  if (oText.length == 1) {
    setText(el, text);

  } else {
    oText.pop();
    setText(el, oText.join(' '));
    setTimeout(function(){annoyUser(el, text)}, 100);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    annoyUser(document.getElementById('d0'), 'hello world')
  }, 1000);
}

</script>

<div id="d0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
 metus sapien, lobortis non dictum et, mollis vitae lorem. Nulla facilisi. Morbi eget
 ante diam.</div>
```